# 68–95–99.7 rule mean normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

if I have data that satisfy 68–95–99.7 rule, does it mean the data is normally distributed? Thanks

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: the answer would necessarily be a bit vague ... it doesn't exactly mean that you have a normal distribution, but it presumably means you won't go wrong, or at least won't go wrong too much, if you treat it as a normal distribution.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko by normal, I mean gaussian normal distribution. what other possible distribution that satisfy 68–95–99.7 rule

Comment: if you have data, that would be finite data (some discrete distribution given by a table with finitely many entries), and you may only model it with Gaussuan normal, which is continuous, if you decide you wish to model it that way for convenience, and to use the theory that goes with Gaussuan normal.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko I see. Actually I am wondering as well, if a data is normally distributed, does it always satisfy 68–95–99.7 rule

Comment: Yes, it does, except I don't really remember the numbers to confirm, and the so called [$z$-scores table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) is likely to give a little bit more precise numbers.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the distribution is not necessarily normal if it satisfies the $68-95-99.7$ rule.  Take a normal distribution, then move all the events that are within $(\mu+0.25 \sigma, \mu + 0.75 \sigma)$, some of them to the mean and some of them to $\mu + 0.99 \sigma$  Do the same for the ones within the range $(\mu - 0.75 \sigma, \mu - 0.25 \sigma)$ in the other direction.  It should be clear that the mean has not changed, and you can choose the fraction to move farther to keep $\sigma$ the same.  You now have a distribution that is not normal but satisfies $68-95-99.7$ just fine. In the other direction, yes if the distribution is normal it will satisfy $68-95-99.7$ as those values are calculated from the normal distribution.